# Can I access a mySQL DB created in phpMyAdmin with a web app that runs with the IDE's tomcat?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, xampp

I hope I don't make it very confusing. So, for a school project I need to make a Spring MVC webapp that runs with a simple tomcat and connects to a DB. I downloaded xampp and made a DB with phpMyAdmin, but also run my app with an embedded tomcat server. I'm not exactly sure why but this seems problematic as I cannot access localhost. Is there a way to connect my app to the phpMyAdmin DB? If not, what would be an easy way to create and access a DB (I need only a really simple schema of one table)?? Any advice would help a ton!

Comment: If it is an example project, the easiet is to use H2 in memory database.

Answer (score 0):

If the web app is for long run i would suggest use of Hibernate ORM, you need to config and with few lines of code it will be live and runing, for just for trial or learning, H2 is a good options as [@zlaval](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9417843/zlaval) said in comments. And you can use any Database with Hibernate ORM, with one or two hours of research and studying you can achieve the task you searching for easily.

If you need to go for hibernate there there is some explained and easy steps to do so with hibernate ORM.
https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/getting-started-with-hibernate-annotations